# Strange pattern-matching fail in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I've wrote the following function:

```
addToDT :: (Ord a) => DocumentTable a -> [a] -> DocumentTable a
addtoDT t [] = t
addToDT t (x:xs) =
   addToDT DocumentTable { tableLength = tableLength t + maybe 0 (const 1) (M.lookup x (table t))
                         , table = M.insertWith (+) x 1 (table t)
                         } xs
```

A `DocumentTable` being a Map that stores its length:

```
data DocumentTable a = DocumentTable { table :: Map a Int
                                     , tableLength :: Int
                                     }
```

`addToDT` makes a map containing for each different `a` in the list its number of occurence.

When I use it, I get `Non-exhaustive patterns in function addToDT`. `traceShow` showed me that it occured when addToDT is called with the empty list. If I replace addToDT by:

```
addToDT :: (Ord a) => DocumentTable a -> [a] -> DocumentTable a
addToDT t xxx
  | null xxx = t
  | otherwise = addToDT DocumentTable { tableLength = tableLength t + maybe 0 (const 1)(M.lookup x (table t))
                                      , table = M.insertWith (+) x 1 (table t)
                                      } xs
  where (x:xs) = xxx
```

Then it works… but I don't really understand why. Could someone explain to me why the pattern matching fails?

Comment: `-Wall` will point out errors like this.

Comment: You misspelled `addToDT` as `addtoDT` (lowercase "t") in the empty-list case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
addtoDT t [] = t    -- this is another function since `to` isn't `To`
```

:)

Comment: Mmmh… that's embarrassing. Thanks a lot!